# Blueprints in Flask vs Apps in Django

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and noticed something called Blueprint in Flask. I searched it and now I am using it in my Flask project. I had already worked in Django and I guess Blueprints are the Flask's equivalent of Apps in Django. Is my thinking and approach right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask is a micro framework and Django a full scale framework.

Blueprints have a similar relation to apps: they are more simplistic. But except of that they serve the same purpose: extending an web application with reusable code collections.